# Upgrading from 32 bit Windows7 to 64 bit WIn7 so as to match with 64 bit CPU

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Vista 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit upgrade?](https://superuser.com/questions/59724/windows-vista-32-bit-to-windows-7-64-bit-upgrade)

I erroneously installed windows 7 32 bit on a 64bit CPU. Is there any easy way to upgrade to 64 bit OS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you must re-install. There is no upgrade path.

Comment: can I re-install win 64 using the upgrade installation path or would I need to remove 32 bit OS and then install 64 bit OS or keep it as a separate installation?

Comment: @Marcos - You must reinstall.  You can't do any kind of in-place upgrade.

Comment: Wipe it and start over is the only path.

Comment: I am screwed up now, since I don't want to lose my data