# Can Windows 7 32bit be upgraded in place to Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Vista 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit upgrade?](https://superuser.com/questions/59724/windows-vista-32-bit-to-windows-7-64-bit-upgrade)
>   [Upgrading from 32 bit Windows7 to 64 bit WIn7 so as to match with 64 bit CPU](https://superuser.com/questions/319073/upgrading-from-32-bit-windows7-to-64-bit-win7-so-as-to-match-with-64-bit-cpu)

I can't get a straight answer on this, and please DO NOT close this question and redirect to the endless other questions which also provide unclear answers. I'm looking for a yes or a no.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: .............. NO

Comment: @BeamingMel-Bin: It **is** a duplicate.

Comment: [No, you must re-install. There is no upgrade path.](http://superuser.com/a/319075/23133) Seems like a simple Yes or No to me. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [microsoft FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions) :

You cannot upgrade from a 32-bit OS to a 64-bit OS or vice versa. You will have to backup data, clean install and then reinstall the software apps that you are going to use.

*Keys are architecture neutral, the same key will activate either 32 bit or 64 bit but you can only use it once.*

Comment: "Once" can be unclear. The key can only be active on one machine at the same time.