# How can I install Windows 7 Upgrade 64 bit when I only have full 32 bit installs of Vista and XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Vista 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit upgrade?](https://superuser.com/questions/59724/windows-vista-32-bit-to-windows-7-64-bit-upgrade)

I have discs for the following versions of Windows:

- 32 bit Windows XP (full)
- 32 bit Windows Vista (full)
- 64 bit Windows 7 (upgrade)

When I tried to install Windows 7 on a new hard drive, I got an error saying that my key was bad. It's my understanding that this is because I was trying a full install, and I'm only licensed to upgrade.

I then installed Vista (which I'm running right now), and booted from the Windows 7 disc, selected the Upgrade option, and it tells me to remove the disc, reboot, and upgrade from the existing Windows installation. When I do that, though, it tells me that I cannot upgrade the 32 bit Vista to the 64 bit Windows 7.

Is there anything I can do to install Windows 7 with these discs?

Comment: Which **editions** of Windows Vista and Windows 7 are involved?

Comment: Have you tried with custom installation rather than upgrade?

Comment: @avirk Custom would be ideal in this case, since they only installed Vista to install Windows 7. :)

Comment: Both editions are professional. The custom install was what I did with 7, and it installed, but never got further than product code checking.

Comment: @iglvzx but they can't upgrade Vista 32-bit to windwos-7 64-bit directly they have to make a clean install.  See [Microsoft answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/upgrading-from-vista-32-bit-to-7-64-bit/967911ef-09b3-4d74-8b69-c3d97207b288)

Comment: @avirk Can't "custom" mean the same thing as "clean" when installing Windows? I was not talking about upgrading

Comment: It just didn't seem my 7 upgrade disc is capable of a clean install. Old versions of windows I remember let you put in an old disc to check, but that didn't seem available anymore.

Comment: @iglvzx yes that is.

Comment: No you can make a clean install just skip the step to enter the product key and then try it after installing.

Comment: It didn't let me skip it. It was in the setting up for first use dialog.

Comment: Follow this [guide](http://www.mydigitallife.info/clean-install-windows-7-with-upgrade-media-and-product-key-on-formatted-or-empty-blank-hard-drive/)

Answer (score -1):

I ended up getting this to work. After Vista was installed, I put the Windows 7 upgrade disc in and rebooted. I installed Windows 7 using the custom install, and didn't touch the partitions, so it detected there was an old windows install on the drive (and saved the directory to windows.old). I left the key blank and unchecked the activation box (not sure if this was necessary or not), and finished the install. Then once in Windows, I just put my normal product code in, and it activated.

Comment: you have did same as the instruct in the guide I refer you. Congrates!